# How to let the coodinates of the cursor follow the cursor when hovering over a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code always shows the coordinates of the cursor below the cursor:

```js
function showCoords(e) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coor = "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = coor;
  var bx = document.getElementById("box");
  bx.style.left = e.pageX - 50;
  bx.style.top = e.pageY + 20;
}

function clearCoords() {
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body onmousemove="showCoords(event)">
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="abs" onmousemove="showCoords(event)" onmouseout="clearCoords()"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box" style="width:100px; height:30px; position:absolute"></div>
</body>
```

I only want the coordinates to be visible when the mouse pointer is hovering over the yellow rectangle.
If I change `<body onmousemove="showCoords(event)">`  to `<body>`, the coordinates are never visible.
How do I get the coordinates be visible only when hovering over the yellow rectangle?

Comment: Regardless of applying a name for the `ShowCoords` function and then calling it with anther name (`showCoords`, the `s` is not capitol as the function name), at first glance, removing the `onmousemove` listener from `body` should do the trick.

Comment: You asked [a question like this](/q/74282147/4642212) yesterday. The advice there was: _“Remove the `onmousemove` attribute and try `addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {`…`});` instead. This way the `mousemove` is bound to the entire page, so the updates occur from mouse moves from the entire page.”_ If you want this to apply only to the rectangle, that would be `document.getElementById("box").addEventListener`.

Comment: @ths Thank you, I didn't see that. Problem solved in a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `onmousemove` listener from the body to the element you want to listen on - `div.abs` in this case.

I'd recommend not using the `onmousemove` attribute, in favour of using an entirely javascript solution - just to keep javascript-y things together.  Something like (untested)

```js
var listenOn = document.querySelector(".abs");
listenOn.addEventListener("mousemove", ShowCoords);
```